# Testing MassTransit consumer with mediator

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, masstransit

I have consumer CarCreatedConsumer which I want to unit test

```
public class CarCreatedConsumer: IConsumer<CarCreatedEvent>
{
   private readonly IMediator _mediator;
   public CarCreatedConsumer(IMediator mediator)
   {
        _mediator = mediator;
   }
   public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CarCreatedEvent> context)
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

Using MassTransit.Testing I'm trying to write test for event consumer

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests
{
   private ServiceProvider _provider;
   private InMemoryTestHarness _harness;

   [SetUp]
   public void SetUp()
   {
     _provider = new ServiceCollection()
       .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
       {
          cfg.AddConsumer<CarCreatedConsumer>();
       }).AddMediator()
      .BuildServiceProvider(true);
         
      _harness = _provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
   }
   
  [Test]
  public async Task MessageShouldBeConsumed()
  {
     await _harness.Start();
    try
    {
     await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send<CarCreatedEvent>(new 
     {
        CarId = Guid.NewGuid.ToString(),
        CarOwnerName = "John Stuart"
        ...
     }
        // Always false
        Assert.True(_harness.Consumed.Select<CarCreatedEvent>().Any());
    }
    finally
    {
       await _harness.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expect this to return true but it fails (returns false). Obviously I'm doing something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: If you debug and put a breakpoint in the consumer; does it hit?

Comment: nope, I'm thinking that maybe I have issues with injecting  mediatR in the consumer constructor.

Comment: Yeah, but they are both registered in the service provider - you could try it without just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test harness usage is suspect, and is also using an obsolete version of the configuration. I'd suggest [reading the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html#consumer) on the current test harness and how to test your consumer.